# Handlebars.js load precompiled template just in time

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js, precompile

I use handlebars for one of my projects and I want to speed up the loading times. Right now, there are a few precompiled handlebar templates in the HTML page. Thus, the browser loads the templates even though it will probably not need them.
In order to speed thing up, I want these precompiled javascript templates to load just in time. That means, when a user clicks a button I want the browser to request the necessary data from the server and not earlier. This will decrease the server load and increase the page speed (since the chance that the users needs that button is low).

My question is: how do I load the data from the server? I've seen plenty tutorials using templates that aren't precompiled and just load an HTML file and compile it in the browser, but how do I load the script generated by `handlebars`?

Some code:

```
$("#select-server-button").on "click", ->
    # Load template file located in /static/templates/myTemplate.js
    myTemplate = Handlebars.templates['myTemplate'];
```

Comment: having extra templates in the page should not slow down page loading, unless you're talking about tons of huge unused templates. in short, a 100kb pages loads at about the same speed as a 20kb page... you can simply use jQuery.load() to add html into the page from another file.

Comment: @dandavis Well, these templates are not in the page, they're external files (template1.handlebars or template1.js after precomipling). If I had these templates in inside the HTML page (and not as external resources), then, you would be right. But all the templates are precompiled and thus in external files (that need to be loaded).

Comment: ahh, i see. withuot seeing any code, all we can do is speculate on that stuff. you likely need to move code from a ready() event to a scroll or click event, but it matters how it's being loaded in the first place when you're re-arranging that loading.

Comment: @dandavis there is no much code (yet) but I added it. The question might appear more complex than it is: I simply want to load a precompiled template (e.g. `/static/templates/myTemplate.js`) from my server. I should mention that I'm not very experienced in Javascript (Coffeescript) and I do as little work as possible in JavaScript.